# MySQL type for storing years and 'year unknown'

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table "photos" with a column "year" for storing the year of production of each photo. The type I use is `int` and 0 for 'unknown'. 
So I often have to say:

```
if($year || $year == "0"){
    $query = ...
```

instead of just:

```
if($year){
    $query = ...
```

Is there a best practice which data type is good for storing year-values? I could use `varchar`, but then I have to look for input values like 'thisisnotayear' etc.
Or could one use the `YEAR` type, but how do I then query "year unknown" from the database? - i mean for example in lists like:

```
2002
2001
2000
year unknown
```

(which the user can use to filter photos)

Is `YEAR` a good choice or are there problems to be expected?

Comment: There' `NULL`, which is sql-eze for "unknown". I wouldn't use `0`. That is technically a perfectly valid year. `where yearfield IS NULL` would get you all of those unknown years.

Comment: `int` type for a date, you sure you want to do that?

Comment: just miss year off, it will be null then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the type YEAR and set this field to ALLOW NULL like this:

```
****`year` year(4) DEFAULT NULL,*****

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `year` year(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

in PHP use:

```
if(! empty($year)){
```